# Windows Phone Binding

Tags: binding, windows-phone

In my RoomView.xaml I have:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding myStrings, Mode=TwoWay}"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

In my constructor I am doing:

```
 var myStrings = new List<string>{"Usmaan","Carl","Andy","Saul"};
 DataContext = myStrings;
```

Yet nothing is being spat out on the page when I load the application.

Can anyone see where I am going horribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext of your page is already set to the `List` object, so you just need to set the binding like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding, Mode=TwoWay}"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Alternatively, you could create an object that has a `MyStrings` property and use it as the DataContext of the page. Then you could bind the `ListBox` like you did `{Binding myStrings, Mode=TwoWay}` while also being able to bind other controls to other properties of that object (that's the principle of ViewModels).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm now having trouble with showing a collection of images using Binding. The URL to the question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843765/windows-phone-image-binding